# Base R shade between lines having NA

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is there a possible way to shade an area between two `lines` using Base R given these two constraints:

- I can't use `ggplot2` because other parts of my app will not work (a `Shiny` `clickId` limitation; more specifically, using `ggplot2`'s `clickId` does not give the real x and y values of the data).
- I also can't use `polygon` because `NA`s are present in my data, which makes the "shade" created by `polygon`close prematurely.

Here is a SSCCE (excluding the `Shiny` components):

```
#my sample data
vals_time <- c(1:10)
vals_line1 <- c(8, 9, NA, NA, 7, 8, 7, NA, 9, 4)
vals_line2 <- c(4, 5, NA, NA, 6, 10, 8, NA, 5, 2)

#create line graphs without the shade
plot(x = vals_time, y = vals_line1, type = "l", ylim = c(0,11))
lines(x= vals_time, y = vals_line2)
```

Here's how I used the `polygon` function:

```
polygon(x = c(vals_time, vals_time[10:1]),
        y = c(vals_line1, vals_line2[10:1]),
        col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.5))
```

Comment: I'm currently thinking of an excruciating workaround to this: find the consecutive sets of x with no NAs and do a polygon "shade" for each complete set. But before I dive into this, is there an easier way?

Comment: Please provide a **minimal, self contained example**. Check these links for general ideas, and how to do it in R: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [**here**](http://www.sscce.org/), [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html), and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your data by the na values and then use `polygon` on the splitted data. I would first create a `data.frame`. Then you can `split` the `data.frame` on `NA` and use `na.omit` to leave out `NA` values.  Finally use `lapply` and `polygon` to plot the data.

```
df <- data.frame(time = vals_time, 
                 l1 = vals_line1, 
                 l2 = vals_line2)
plot(x = df$time, y = df$l1, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 11))
lines(x = df$time, y = df$l2)
lst <- lapply(split(df, cumsum(is.na(df$l1))), na.omit)
lapply(lst, function(d) 
  polygon(x = c(d$time, rev(d$time)), y = c(d$l1, rev(d$l2)), col = rgb(1,0,0,0.5)))
```